# How to avoid misrepresented data by 3 days in the rolling mean graph in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I calculated **7day_rolling_avg** because irregularities in covid data by this code:

```
covid_df['7day_rolling_avg'] = covid_df['New cases'].rolling(7).mean()
```

But, by plotting a graph on top of each other new graph can be seen misrepresented by 3-4 days.

Code:

```
covid_df[covid_df["Country"]=="India"]['New cases'].plot()
covid_df[covid_df["Country"]=="India"]['7day_rolling_avg'].plot()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Can someone give me any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `center=True` in [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html)

```
covid_df['7day_rolling_avg'] = covid_df['New cases'].rolling(7, center=True).mean()
```

Output:

[image: centered rolling mean]

Comment: @AkashKumar you can also post the image link as comment, and I'll do it myself ;)

Comment: That sounds great!!! Here is the link of the image: https://ibb.co/dPtSc8V